# Como faço para redirecionar a Exception para uma página de erro?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Como faço para redirecionar UsernameNotFoundException para uma página?

```
if ( user == null ) {
   log.info( "Email " + email + " não é um ususário cadastrado." );
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException( "Email " + email + " não é um ususário cadastrado." );
}
```

---

Acho que eu não fui muito claro na minha pergunta, o Spring devolve uma página de erro, com a seguinte mensagem:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Jul 31 15:20:43 BRT 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Forbidden, status=403). Access Denied

Gostaria de que a mensagem de erro fosse definida através de uma página HTML criada por mim.

Estou usando AngularJS com Spring, como faço para mapear isso?

Comment: Respondi sua [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225487/) sobre o mesmo problema, aquela [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225527/53279) não lhe ajudou?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a propriedade **authentication-failure-url** ao seu xml de configuração do spring-security

Exemplo:

```
<form-login login-page="/"
        login-processing-url="/login"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" 
        default-target-url="/userhome" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/error" 
         />
```