# Forbbiden 403 - Redirect

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Como exibir uma mensagem de erro quando recebo um erro 403, gostaria de que a mensagem de erro fosse definida através de uma página HTML criada por mim. Tem alguma forma de redirecionar? Usando o AngularJS ou o próprio Spring?

Estou usando AngularJS com Spring, como faço para mapear isso?

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 31 15:20:43 BRT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente colocar uma página customizada dentro da pasta `templates` com o nome `error.html` ou `error.jsp`, o spring vai reconhecer e exibir caso haja algum erro.

Dentro dessa página você vai ter acesso a algumas variáveis. Ex.: `error`, `path` e `message`.

Obs.: O nome da página de erro deve sempre ser error + extensão do seu sistema de templates